# Spring Web Flow 2 end state

Tags: spring, spring-webflow-2

I have a simple question. I am working out a simple application with few tabs. Application uses few external services to query for data and displays it for better data mining experience. Also I decided to incorporate Spring Web-Flow mainly to do some learning on the subject.

By going through specs of web-flow, they display clearly defined logical view-states and transitions and other stuff that gradually works itself towards some inevitable end-state. Now each state has it's own scope which I really like. You can put information and pass it forth and back between states and even other flows but what boggles my mind is that my application is just for browsing. I don't have a clear end-state unless user shuts the browser down or closes a tab whenever he digest what he was looking for or gets bored. What happens to all instances of DTO's and other stuff I have put in flow-scopes ?

According to http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/pr5/api/org/springframework/webflow/EndState.html this API spec, end state terminates flow and also destroys its session which I assume destroys all of the scopes filled with data, so I am worried I have may have a memory leak. Or does webflow session has some timeout and conditional memory management that in the end falls to the mercy of garbage collector ?

Could someone back me up on this one ?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have default settings that you can override:

```
<webflow:flow-execution-repository max-executions="5" max-execution-snapshots="10" />
```

these will prevent you from having any memory leaks. the old executions and snapshots will be removed.

Comment: That is, those limit the number of concurrent "flows" a single user can have active at one time. If some multi-tab clicking or forking off "sub paths" requires a new execution or snapshot, the oldest ones will be deleted. If you then try to revisit/reuse one of those, you'll either get an error or get redirected to start a new one. (I think we had to implement something custom so that the user doesn't see the underlying SWF error.)